# (python) Xlib.display.Display() throwing AttributeError module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'

Tags: python, python-3.11

I am running a Windows 10 machine with python 3.11 installed, and am facing an unexpected error.

The issue arose when I was attempting to lock my mouse, I've been tackling this issue for a while now, and I've finally found a good lead.

I tried this code:

```py
from Xlib.display import Display
from Xlib import X
import contextlib
from time import sleep

DISPLAY=":0"

disp = Display(DISPLAY)
screen = disp.screen()
root = screen.root


@contextlib.contextmanager
root.grab_pointer(owner_events=True,
    event_mask=0,
    time=X.CurrentTime,
    pointer_mode=X.GrabModeAsync,
    keyboard_mode=X.GrabModeAsync,
    confine_to=0,
    cursor=0)

sleep(5)

disp.ungrab_pointer(time=X.CurrentTime)
```

It seems to be Display(DISPLAY) causing the issue, the whole error being:

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'socket' has no attribute 'AF_UNIX'
  File "G:\Downloads\PY SCRIPTS\mouselock.py", line 8, in <module>
    disp = Display(DISPLAY)
```

Leaving Display empty ( as "Display()" ) will not work, though I have seen it used in others' scripts- it does not work in my case. This has led me to believe this is an issue with me operating on Windows 10, and/or python 3.11.

Anything I can do to resolve this issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user11717481 In order to block the computer user's cursor movement, I've heard that using the "grab_pointer" function in this context is what I'm looking for. However, in line 8, the aforementioned error is thrown. I've tried my best to research my issue, but I am only shown socket search results--I do not have control over the socket in this context. My research has led me to believe that it is incompatibility with Windows. However, I still lack understanding, and cannot verify that. I appreciate the hasty response.

Comment: That code is *extremely* Unix-specific.  If there's a way to do the equivalent on Windows, it's going to have absolutely nothing in common with this code.

Comment: @jasonharper Ah, is that so? That is indeed unfortunate. However, I thank you for confirming. You've saved me a great deal of time.